# I want to setText which i have got from previous activity as intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
   /*I have problem with intent that i can't settext which i have got from getIntent from previous activity*/ 


    public class Done extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_done);
            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.donetxt);
            int tappedapples=0;
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
            rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
            /*I want to setText which i have got from previous activity*/
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras!=null){
                int apples = extras.getInt("tappedapples",0);
                text.setText(Integer.parseInt("tappedapples"));
             }
        }
    }
```

/*I have problem with intent that i can't settext which i have got from getIntent from previous activity*/

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
int apples = extras.getInt("tappedapples",0);
text.setText(Integer.parseInt("tappedapples"));
```

To:

```
int apples = extras.getInt("tappedapples",0);
text.setText(apples+"");
```

Comment: Yuppi its working and i want to draw objects which user have colleted in result activity

Comment: @donfuxx +1 up for your _Awesome_ answer.

Comment: If i want to make tutorial of my app how to do it?

Comment: what do you mean with making tutorial of your app? @user3248914

Comment: Maybe do a screen capturing video and upload to youtube?

Comment: Ok and i have one question too that my app is working as expected but the problem is my objects overlapping. So how to prevent this?

Comment: what do you mean with overlapping objects?